# Membership.ValidateUser cached

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have created a WinForm that is calling Membership.ValidateUser(user, pass) that is using the Client Application Services. It was working fine until today. When I changed my password on the SQL backend the Membership.ValidateUser seems to be cached because it is still using my old password.

I went as far as stopping IIS and stopping the SQL service but the Membership.ValidateUser still accepts my old username / password with the services disabled. No exceptions are thrown.

I have also enabled System.Diagnostics tracing in the App.Config but it doesn't even look like it is connecting to the service.

The computer has been rebooted and all cookies deleted. I completed removed the serviceUri from the app.config but still not exception and it still accepts my old username / password.

I was able to create a new Winform application and it accepted my new password against the same service just fine.

So the problem seems to be that the old Winform application has cached something somewhere but I don't know where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to solve the problem.
It seems that the application has a setting called ConnectivityStatus.IsOffline that is application / user specific that I have to hardcode to "False" so that it always tries my service. It seems that once my application couldn't reach the service then it went into an "offline" mode. Once in the "offline" mode not even a reboot would pull it back out of the "offline" mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.clientservices.connectivitystatus.isoffline(v=vs.110).aspx